# How can I find the true reason for the time consumed by the UI thread on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, gps

I have studied a lot in SO to find an answer for this but non of the documents can explain the performance phenomena I measure in my app. The standard answer is to log the time at the beginning and end of the onDraw method and then the delta is the time consumed. Of course I have done this but it does not explain the entire time consumed by the application before the screen is refreshed. So I wonder whether there is an element of activity on system level which I am not aware of.

Now more details:
The app works on a Nexus 7 with Android Version 5.1.1.

Purpose of the app is to show graphically the layout of a golf course while the player moves over the fairway. The player position is retrieved by GPS signals (onLocationChange). Whenever the position of the player has changed (which is happening almost every second when he is walking), the graphical layout of the area has to be redrawn since distances, orientation etc. have now changed with the new view point.

(I think it would not help to copy the code here because it would be too much to study. Furthermore this is more a principle question about understanding the architecture correctly.)

To simplify it we can say that the app has two main tasks:
A) retrieving new location information via GPS in a short interval of 1 or 2 seconds (depending on the movement).
B) Drawing the golf course's hole layout again based on the new position as
given from A.

The phenomena I measure from my logging over a period of 15 minutes in which many redraws happen naturally is that there is obviously a third big unknown time consumer beside the computations of A) and B). Lets call it X). The *expected* sequence in my logs would be like:
A
B
A
B
...
What I notice is this:
A
B
A
X
B
...
A
B
X
A
A
A
A
B

It means the duration of X which can grow to 5 seconds (while B performs in an average of 200ms) is so big that once it is done, obviously a number of queued events of A (new GPS positions) arrive in an interval of milliseconds.

Furthermore I notice that the duration of X grows with the time the app runs so that at the end the app cannot respond anymore.

I have read about the rendering thread and wonder whether this is the candidate for X.  But what I understood from those documents is that the rendering thread time is covered by the time consumed in onDraw (B in my example). The impression I get however is that the program updates the canvas (B) and that then the device (or the OS ?) needs some considerable time to make it visible. However I could not find any documentation or SO case giving such an indication. So, if somebody could explain how the system mechanism works conceptually and (ideally) how this explains the phenomena measured above, it would be highly appreciated.

Last remark: Of course I have read a lot about how to keep the UI thread responsive, using Asynctask etc. I also intend to implement this but I cannot expect based on the measured phenomena above that this will cure my problem. It might reduce the time slice for B on the main thread but as long as I cannot identify the main consumer of X, it is unlikely Asynctask can reduce the overall performance of the program.

Comment: Could be the garbage collection kicking in. Could you post your logcat log?

Comment: The Android Device Monitor could give you a better insight.

Comment: Hi Alex, In order to get logs independently from my development environment, I write to a log file on the device's external storage. Here a short extract from it which shows the phenomena best:

Comment: Here a few relevant records:   21/07/2016 07:48:57.832;  onDraw DrawHole;  Used Memory: 16 Free Memory:7
21/07/2016 07:48:57.850;  onDraw;  DrawHole executed
21/07/2016 07:49:04.841;  Main onLocationChanged;  entry
21/07/2016 07:49:04.846;  Main onLocationChanged;  Lat: 51.1684613 Lng: 6.7121936 Distance to previous: 0.16687705536916447

Answer (score 0):

Systrace will allow you to profile your app and see what is taking up the time. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace.html